# Dangling meta character '*' near index 6

Tags: java

When I'm replacing the character `*` with an empty string I get the following exception : `Dangling meta character '*' near index 6`.

Here is my code :

```
String siteDelimit=subjectStudy.getSubject().getSubjCdDelimiter();
//think siteDelimit having **
subject.setSubjectCode(subject.getSubjectCode().replaceAll(siteDelimit, ""));
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: it is java code

Comment: It has the JavaScript tag.

Comment: yes but i'm using in java code.is any problem?

Comment: Yes, you have the JavaScript tag but this is not JavaScript. It's Java.

Comment: `*` has special meaning in a regular expression. You need to escape it if you mean it literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regex, therefore you get this error. If you don't want to use regex, you can use the method which doesn't take regexes, i.e. [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))